# Passing class as a Parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form where I do some validations. When I instance the form I pass a class as parameter so then I can update a value on that class.

```
Bussines _bussines = new Bussines ();

public frmUsuario(Bussines b)
{
    _bussines = b;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Instantiating the form

```
frmUsuario fUsuarios = new frmUsuario(this);
fUsuarios.ShowDialog();
```

So, my question is: according to OOP, is it ok to do? It seems like lazy work-around to me, but I don't know any easier option. Is there a better option?

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: The `Bussines _bussines = new Bussines ();` can just be `Bussines _bussines;` if you don't have any other constructors that does not set a value to `_bussines`. No need to create the object twice.

Comment: Also, is this WPF or Winforms? If it is WPF there are better ways to do this than passing it in to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, i've already changed it on my code. And it's winforms. I guess i should add the tag on the question

Comment: You are not passing a class as a parameter. You are passing an instance of that class as a parameter. Other than that, it is always good to see people taking the time to learn how to program and OOP. Wish you the best!

Comment: Is it okay? As long as you're consistent and clear about what you're doing I don't see a problem with it. I don't usually like side-effect scenarios and this seems pretty side-effecty to me. I'd definitely add a comment to let people know.

Comment: @Renan thank you. It's always good to learn how to do things properly.

Comment: @itsme86 by saying "this seems pretty side-effecty" what do you mean?

Comment: @Vlocks Mostly just that it should be clear from the caller that something is going to be happening to the object. I feel like you might be violating the Separation of Concerns principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns. You're creating a tightly coupled situation which you usually want to avoid.

Comment: Thank you @itsme86. I'm going to remodel my application. Also thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner and more indirect way would be to use an interface.

*IMO*

- your form constructor should not depend on a parameter
- your form should be able to be shown without anything specific (Businees)
- your form should exhibit a nice UX according its state

But as others cleverly pointed out, anything could be correct, it's more a matter of not setting a trap to yourself in future by doing such restrictions.

Example:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Business
    {
    }

    public interface IBusinessHandler
    {
        Business Business { get; set; }
        void Execute();
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form, IBusinessHandler
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region IBusinessHandler Members

        public Business Business { get; set; }

        public void Execute()
        {
            // check that we can continue
            if (Business == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Business property not set");
                // or whatever else appropriate
                return;
            }

            // do some work on it
            var s = Business.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Work done !");
        }

        #endregion
    }

    internal class Demo
    {
        public Demo()
        {
            IBusinessHandler handler = new Form1();
            handler.Business = new Business();
            handler.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the interface? Just expose the property and you are done.

Comment: That's right, I mean we could debate endlessly on this; my example is just the first thing that came out of my mind :)

Comment: It would make sense if you had more than one form that interacted with the `Business` class and you wanted a common `API`.

Comment: Thank you @Aybe. I've chosen your answer as the right one because it shows me the concept of intercace (or a part of it). But also thanks to ja72. I will take both answers into account

Comment: @ja72 +1 There's a strong selling point in your answer (constructor) !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no because .NET code expects a parameterless constructor for the form.

Think of how you use `OpenFileDialog`. You create an instance, and then you assign properties. The same goes here.

```
{
    Business item=new Business() { Name="Yoko" };
    //
    BusinessForm dlg=new BusinessForm();
    dlg.Business=item;
    if (dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        item=dlg.Business;
    }
}
```

with the form code

```
public class Business
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOk { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name); } }
}

public partial class BusinessForm : Form
{
    Business business;

    public BusinessForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.business=new Business();
    }

    public Business Business
    {
        get { return business; }
        set { business=value; }
    }
    public bool IsOk { get { return business.IsOk; } }
}
```